# Explainer / Refiner / Illuminator count frozen?

Tags: support, badges

My current recommended next badge is the [Refiner badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner), which therefore appears with a progress meter on my [user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris). I noticed recently that its progress meter seems to have stopped moving.

I have started to pay closer attention to this counter, and I'm fairly certain that the following recent answers should have counted towards this badge, but did not:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319778/354577
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429564/354577
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430596/354577

I realize that some badge counters do not update immediately, but the first answer in this list is a week old.

Is there currently a problem with these badge counters?

I do see that other users have earned both the Explainer and Refiner badges within the last 24 hours, so I don't think this is a site-wide problem.

Comment: Did you change more than just tags?

Comment: @NineBerry, I often edit tags on questions I answer, and these three edits were tag edits. Do tag edits not count towards these badges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag edits do not count towards these badges. You need to actually change the text of the question.

These are the criteria from [the documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) (Feb 2017):

- Edit n questions each within 12 hours of answering it
- Answers must have a score of 1 or greater.
- Self-answers don't count.
- Only body and title edits on the question count, tag-only edits do not.
- The question must remain open.

Comment: That may well be my problem. Do you have a reference that confirms this? The description of these three badges doesn't make that distinction clear.

Comment: @Chris: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/175248